# Trying to install nasm on my ubuntu 14.04 LTS but it get error

Tags: apt, software-installation, software-center

I get these errors when i try to install nasm using central software...

```
installArchives() failed: (Reading database ...
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 221927 files and directories currently installed.)

Preparing to unpack .../nasm_2.10.09-1_amd64.deb ...

Unpacking nasm (2.10.09-1) ...

dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archive/nasm_2.10.09-1_amd64.deb (--unpack):

trying to overwrite '/usr/share/man/man1/ldrdf.1.gz', which is also in package nasm-rdoff 2.11.08-2

dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)

Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...

Errors were encountered while processing:

 /var/cache/apt/archives/nasm_2.10.09-1_amd64.deb

Error in function:
```

Comment: You are missing a part of the error message. And you have conflicting software: remove nasm-rdoff before installing this please and try again.

Comment: try removing or purging nasm-rdoff before installing nasm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run the following commands in an open terminal:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get remove nasm-rdoff
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

If it gives you trouble, run this instead:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo dpkg -r nasm-rdoff
sudo apt-get install nasm
```

It looks like nasm provides RDOFF tools so nasm-rdoff is probably not needed.

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.13